# Can I nest TestCases with Nose?

Tags: python, testing, bdd, nose

I've become a fan of nested test case contexts in things like RSpec and Jasmine, and I'm wondering if there are any Nose plugins that implement a test finder that allows you to nest classes as context.  The resulting tests would look something like the following:

```
from nose.tools import *
from mysystem import system_state

class TestMySystem (TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        system_state.initialize()

    class WhenItIsSetTo1 (TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            system_state.set_to(1)

        def test_system_should_be_1 (self):
            assert_equal(system_state.value(), 1)

    class WhenItIsSetTo2 (TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            system_state.set_to(2)

        def test_system_should_be_2 (self):
            assert_equal(system_state.value(), 2)
```

In the above hypothetical case, `system_state.initialize()` will be called before each test.  I know there is PyVows for doing something like this, and it looks good, but I'm looking for something to plug in to my current project, which already has a number of unittest-/nose-style tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want some of your test to inherit setup code from other tests:

```
from nose.tools import *
from mysystem import system_state

class TestMySystem (TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        system_state.initialize()

class WhenItIsSetTo1 (TestMySystem):
    def setUp(self):
        super(WhenItIsSetTo1, self).setUp()
        system_state.set_to(1)

    def test_system_should_be_1 (self):
        assert_equal(system_state.value(), 1)

class WhenItIsSetTo2 (TestMySystem):
    def setUp(self):
        super(WhenItIsSetTo2, self).setUp()
        system_state.set_to(2)

    def test_system_should_be_2 (self):
        assert_equal(system_state.value(), 2)
```

Be careful when you do this; if you have actual test methods in the parent class, they will also be executed when the child is run (of course).  When I do this, I like to make pure parent test classes that only provide setUp, tearDown & classSetup/ classTearDown.

This should allow you an arbitrary level of nesting, though once you do that you're going to need unit tests for your unit tests...

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know, but you can achieve a similar effect with setup and teardown methods at the [module and package levels](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-packages).

Your example would then become:

```
def setup():
    system_state.initialize()

def teardown():
    system_state.teardown()

class WhenItIsSetTo1 (TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        system_state.set_to(1)

    def test_system_should_be_1 (self):
        assert_equal(system_state.value(), 1)

class WhenItIsSetTo2 (TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        system_state.set_to(2)

    def test_system_should_be_2 (self):
        assert_equal(system_state.value(), 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I'd known about the module-level fixtures, but am really looking for something more general.  For instance, even with module fixtures, I'm limited to 2 levels of context (though 2 levels will suffice for far more cases than 1 level), and I'm forced to create a new module any time I want new context.