# Organize Python unittest tests based on nesting context similar to RSpec

Tags: python, unit-testing, rspec, contextmanager

When writing RSpec tests, I found the nesting context structure it uses very clear and useful:

```rb
describe "a laptop" do
  before(:each) do
  end
  context "progamming" do
    before(:each) do
    end
    it "compiles programs" do
    end
    context "with an external monitor" do
      it "shows editors in multiple displays" do
      end
    end
  end
  context "video gaming" do
    before(:each) do
    end
    context "with normal graphic card" do
      before(:each) do
      end
      it "can not play League of Legends" do
      end
    end
    context "with expensive graphic card" do
      before(:each) do
      end
      it "can play League of Legends" do
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is very easy to share/DRY those setup and teardown code when they are nested, and with the context structure it's also helpful to "think" about the coverage of the specs. I wonder how we typically write Python unittest tests to achieve this. Or the philosophy is just different?

Looks like we can achieve similar setup/teardown code sharing by [inheriting the test class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769068/can-i-nest-testcases-with-nose), but there are still some minor issues, and separating them in different classes doesn't seem to be a very readable/maintainable structure if it goes, say 2 layers deeper.

Answer (score 2):

Do take a look at some of the BDD framework in python.

1. Behave - http://pythonhosted.org/behave/
2. Lettuce - http://lettuce.it/intro/overview.html

Largely modelled after cucumber, the bdd framework in Ruby which was the first story-based framework in RSpec.

Not sure if this answer your question fully, but I hope you will find it useful.

Check out Dan North's blog as well. Real good stuff about the philosophy and principles of development in general.http://dannorth.net/

Also, I think another aspect that you will find useful is the concept of tdd using the outside-in and inside-out appoarch. Rspec/BDD, i think follows the outside-in model . you can have agood look at this discussion which i find really useful https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166409/tdd-outside-in-vs-inside-out

Comment: This is very useful and thanks for the references! I've tried Cucumber before for website integration tests, and it worked well. I am not sure, tho, about using it for other types of stuff that's less scenario-based, for example, database ORM models and utility classes. Seems to be a bit overkill for those cases, and maybe not an optimal solution to have BDD framework and Unittest in a single project. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Automated testing happens at numerous levels and having unittest coverage doesn't mean you don't also want tools for integration testing and functional testing (like you'd get with Selenium). As long as the structure of the tests and boundaries of when to use the BDD tool are clear, having both should not be a problem.